# No matching client found for package name 'com.domain.appname'

Tags: flutter, firebase

When I try to build the Appbundle for the Google Play Console with `flutter build appbundle` I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.domain.appname'

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                             24,3s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

*Of cause I got a real domain of myself and another appname in the package name*

I think I changed the package name everywhere I should but it still doesn't work.

Does anyone have experience with this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you put your google-services.json file inside the android/app directory?

Comment: @DulajAriyaratne yes

Answer (score 0):

if you are using android studio, then press CTRL + SHIFT + R. It is a command for replace. In the search bar search with com.. you can see in the whole project where you have changed the unique package name.